# :hover with <span> elements

Tags: css, image, hover, rollover

I am working with:

```
#top ul li.corner span.right-corner:hover
{
    background-image:url("images/corner-right-over.gif");
    width:4px;
    height:15px;
    float:left;
}

#top ul li.corner span.left-corner:hover
{
    background-image:url("images/corner-left-over.gif");
    float:left;
    width:4px;
    height:15px;
}
```

And I can't seem to get the `:hover` working properly? Not sure why, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: what is "top" in the CSS selectors? if it's an element ID, it should be "#top"

Comment: It didn't print the # sign, it is there in my CSS though.

Comment: @RoBorg - Thank you for the edit, I just logged back in to do the same thing, since two people thought I did forget the "#"

Thanks again

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. Do you want the background image to change only when you hover over the corners?

Comment: This makes little sense, as foxy said. Hard to help you make it work right when "right" isn't defined and isn't clear at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the problem is that SPAN elements display inline by default - meaning they have no height and width. Try explicitly making them block level elements by adding:

```
#top ul li.corner span.right-corner, #top ul li.corner span.left-corner
{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Write `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the first line of your HTML document. Hover support should be enabled for all types of elements.

Comment: good point... inline text, for example, doesn't need to be block.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter noted, "top" is not a valid selector. It should be "#top" or ".top"

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing in IE?  IE7 and below only support `:hover` on `<a>` (not sure about IE8)